# What is the type of "context" in this code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to generate QR codes in my asp.net web application using C#. I found this tutorial online using ZXing library, however it uses "context" variable in the code and I'm not sure what it's type. Here's the piece of code :

```
var writer = new BarcodeWriter();
writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
var result = writer.Write("http://www.dotnetthoughts.net");
var barcodeBitmap = new Bitmap(result);
barcodeBitmap.Save
    (context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg); //what is this context value ?
context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
context.Response.End();
```

Here's the website source : http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-generate-and-read-qr-code-in-asp-net/

Comment: Probably [HttpContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Thank you for your reply, but there is something i still don't get. How come the variable is not defined any where, even in the example in the page you shared ?

Comment: Just because it isn't shown in this code snippet doesn't mean it isn't defined. Ask the blogposter for clarification, we can't guess his code.

Comment: Ok I think I got it now, the problem was to write "Context" instead of "context" to use the page's HTTP Context, and it doesn't require definition

Comment: or the person could have capture the HttpContext into a variable called "context" and used that instead, but did not include it in their post.

Comment: You can also use *HttpContext.Current.Response*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "context" variable is HTTPContext as @Jeroen Vannevel have mentioned in the comments and it's a variable predefined in the page.  But I had to capitalize the "C" (i.e. use "Context" instead of "context") to be able to use it without any definitions